# Can I export keyframe settings in OBS?

Tags: obs

I exported my settings and got a file like this:

```
[General]
Name=Adobe RTMP

[Video]
BaseCX=1920
BaseCY=1080
OutputCX=1920
OutputCY=1080
ColorSpace=601
ColorRange=Partial

[Panels]
CookieId=CB44DC4848BD02DB

[Output]
Mode=Advanced

[SimpleOutput]
VBitrate=4000

[AdvOut]
VBitrate=4000
TrackIndex=1
RecType=Standard
RecTracks=1
FFOutputToFile=true
FFFormat=
FFFormatMimeType=
FFVEncoderId=0
FFVEncoder=
FFAEncoderId=0
FFAEncoder=
FFAudioMixes=1
RescaleRes=1680x1050
RecRescaleRes=1680x1050
FFRescaleRes=1680x1050
```

I know I had to add `[SimpleOutput]` myself, to ensure 4K bitrate for people using advanced or simple UI. I am wondering how I might be able to add a specific setting for Keyframe Interval. I want people to download my settings to have keyframe interval of 2, rather than auto (which is 8.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can! In your `streamEncoder.json` add the following.

```
{
...
      "keyint_sec": 2
...
}
```